# Android RTF to HTML

Tags: java, android, html, android-webview, rtf

I am working on an Android application that allows users to view their documents. However, I've run into the issue of viewing RTF files and/or converting them to HTML. It seems that resources are very limited when searching for help on this. Is there any way to view them with a WebView (similar to the UIWebView for iOS) or are there any libraries out there that actually work for converting from RTF to HTML?

Comment: I don't know of any java libraries or jars you can use.

Answer (score 0):

The Android [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) is not capable of rendering RTF. It is limited to displaying HTML.

Regarding the second part of your question: yes, there are Java libraries which convert RTF to HTML. With their help, an Android app may display the RTF converted to HTML in a WebView.

The ScroogeXHTML RTF converter library for example is used in the TinyRTFViewer app. (Disclosure: I am its author)